# Uso de artículos indeterminados

Tags: artículos

¿Es correcto, conforme a la normativa vigente, omitir un artículo indefinido como **una** cuando hay un sustantivo y un adjetivo como **voz anticuada**? De modo que la oración quede formulada como *Es voz anticuada* y no como *Es una voz anticuada*.
El antiguo Diccionario de Autoridades, no usa en ciertos casos los  artículos definidos. Por ejemplo, en las siguientes definiciones:

> ONUSTO, TA. adj. Cargado, pesado. Es voz tomada de la Latina. Onustus,
> y yá sin uso alguno.
>
> FANO. s. m. Lo mismo que Templo. Es voz antiquada, y tomada del Latino
> Fanum, que significa lo mismo.
>
> ACCENDER. v. a. Lo mismo que encender. Vease. Es voz de ningun uso, y
> puramente Latina. Lat. Accéndere.
>
> CELESTRE. s. m. Lo mismo que Celeste. Es voz antigua, que ya no tiene
> uso.
>
> ADOLESCENTE. s. m. El joven, el mancébo, el que esta en la edád de
> adolescencia. Es voz solo usada en la Poesia, ò jocosamente haciendo
> burla de la afectación. Lat. Adolescens, tis.
>
> ASSUETO, TA. adj. Lo mismo que Acostumbrado. Vease. Es voz puramente
> Latina, y de ningun uso en Castellano. Lat. Assuetus, a, um.

Nótese que se dice `Es voz...` y nunca `Es una voz...`. ¿Es apropiado, así, omitir esta palabra actualmente?

Comment: En la [Nueva gramática](http://www.rae.es/recursos/gramatica/nueva-gramatica) de 2009 se sigue usando la expresión "es voz anticuada" y similares: "es voz opaca", "es voz derivada", "es voz malsonante", "es voz muy ofensiva"...

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias circustancias en las que se pueden omitir los artículos indeterminados, una de ellas es:

> Cuando el adjetivo o predicado nominativo forman una parte del título
>   de la profesión o es una característica intrínseca, se omite el
>   artículo indefinido:
>
> *Mi padre es profesor de inglés | Juan es mal alumno*

Yo diría que los ejemplos que pones podrían entrar dentro de "características intrínsecas" y por lo tanto se puede omitir el artículo.

El ejemplo lo he sacado de aquí: http://www.gramaticas.net/2012/02/ejemplos-de-articulo-indefinido.html pero se puede encontrar información similar en otras páginas o textos sobre gramática española.